# How to add as a mark to a ppp object the count of points that share same coordinates?

Tags: spatstat

In spatstat you have a number of functions that return a logical vector if you have duplicates or a numerical vector with the integers (multiplicities) of length equal to the number of points in the ppp object. I can´t find a function that allows you to add the result of multiplicity as a mark to your ppp object directly. How can you do this? How can you end up with a new ppp object that includes as a mark the count of incidents in each pair of coordinates?

Another way of asking is, how is the ordering of the resulting vector produced by multiplicity.ppp determined? Say you have tested multiplicity in ppp object x and have created a vector based on this "multiple_x".

```
x <- ppp(x = mycoords[,1], y = mycoords[,2],
                   window = window, check = T)
multiple_x <- multiplicity.ppp(x)
```

Can you simply create a new ppp object using the original coordinates and the new vector as a mark?

```
x <- ppp(x = mycoords[,1], y = mycoords[,2],
                   window = window, check = T,
                   marks = multiple_x)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new point pattern using `ppp` as you have proposed.

But it would be much easier to assign the marks to an existing point pattern `X` using the idiom `marks(X) <- value`. (See the help for `marks<-.ppp`)

Example:

```
Y <- X
marks(Y) <- multiplicity(X)
```

Then `Y` is the same pattern as `X` except that each point is marked by an integer indicating the number of points at the same location.

If you wanted to collapse the duplicated points in the point pattern `X`, retaining only one instance of each duplicated point but with a mark indicating its multiplicity, then just do

```
Z <- Y[!duplicated(X)]
```

Examples are given in the help file for `multiplicity.ppp`

Comment: Many thanks Prof. Baddeley (for this and the wonderful package + book)